# How do I count the number of integers in this file using Java?

Tags: java, io

If I have a given `.dat` file which I'm trying to read, how can I count the number of  32-bit integers? I'm getting 2 different answers using 2 different methods.

First method:

```
int size = 0;
try (DataInputStream Input = new DataInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getFD())))){
    while (true) {
        file.skipBytes(4);
        size += 1;
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
System.out.println(size);
```

Second method:

```
File fileRead = new File(file);
ret = fileRead.length() / 4
```

The first method is probably the most accurate since I'm reading 4 bytes each time and skipping it, to get the size of integers being packed sequentially in the file. However, the second method just gives me the direct file size and divided by 4, which is not the same. I think it might be including extra file related data not related to the content.

The first method is good but it is very inefficient for large files. Any idea how I can speed things up and get the number of integers efficiently?

Comment: You can "tokenize" the lines while you read them – provided it's a "text" file; evaluate the tokens to _discover_ if it's an integer or not...then count the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know hoy many times can you read a 32-bit integer from a certain *binary* file, Method 2 is the certain answer.

You must not read your file through a `DataInputStream` unless you are certain that it was written through a `DataOutputStream`, because then it is not just a plain, binary file: Instead, it becomes a *Java Object file*, which will contain *a lot of overhead data* with every object written.

Comment: Could you explain why there is a different size for the 2 approaches? I imagine that for the binary file, the actual file size probably contains data that is not part of the content, so the actual number of 32-bit integers read could be smaller?

Comment: First of all: What is the file's format? Does it contains plain 32-bit words, or does it contain serialized Java objects?